# How to search the publication fee of a journal

Tags: journals, online-publication, fees

What's the correct place on a journal webpage to show the publication fee?

Comment: Wherever they wish or perhaps only through direct contact.

Comment: Why do you think there is a general answer? Or are you designing a new journal and want design advice?

Comment: @SolarMike They won't write explicitly on the website?

Comment: @Buffy I can't find any place telling the publication fee, of any journal

Comment: I guess it may depend on your area of research, but in the humanities and social sciences, never publish in a journal that asks for a publication fee.

Comment: "wherever they wish" means anywhere on the website if they wish to.... But they can choose not to as well... which is why I also put "only through direct contact" - is there a language issue somewhere?

Comment: @SolarMike If it's written on their website, how would they call it or under what category usuallly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://hoffman.physics.harvard.edu/links/Page-charges.php) are some charges for physics journals.

Note: dated 2014

Comment: Great thanks. Info about other physics or materials, engineering journals will be welcome